# Export tab_model() output to a csv in R

Tags: html, r, csv, export, glmmtmb

I'm trying to export the results of a `glmmTMB` model. I am able to format my output using the `tab_model()`, but then I cannot export [this](http://file:///private/var/folders/_w/p1mts31s0x53_zhp37cz6zvh0000gp/T/RtmpJdpult/file3bd947893244.html) HTML file while still maintaining the formatting.

For illustrative purposes, a similar dataset to the one I am using would be the `ChickWeight` dataset in base R.

```
#load packages
library(glmmTMB)
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)

#model
model<-glmmTMB(weight ~ Time + Diet + (1|Chick), family=nbinom2, data=ChickWeight)
```

To view the output in exactly the way I want it in my paper:

```
tab_model(model, transform = NULL, auto.label = FALSE, collapse.ci=TRUE)
```

Which gives me a beautifully formatted table (see [here](http://file:///private/var/folders/_w/p1mts31s0x53_zhp37cz6zvh0000gp/T/RtmpJdpult/file3bd947893244.html)).

I tried to export it as a csv using `write.csv(as.data.frame(summary(model)), "~/Desktop/model output.csv")`, but this solution is not possible for `glmmTMB` models.

**How can I export the HTML file with the same formatting to a CSV (e.g., estimate with CIs in brackets all on the same line)?**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add file = to your code like so: `tab_model(model, transform = NULL, auto.label = FALSE, collapse.ci=TRUE, file = "results.xls")`

Then you can import, manimpulate, save as .csv, and etc. But, note that Excel and R will think it is a 'webpage' even though it is saved with .xls. To fix this you will have to open with Excel and then save as .xls (or .csv or .xlsx)